# Is span $\{[1,0],[0,1]\}$ a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I can't figure this out. I would think that it is a vector space because it has the zero vector, and it seems to me to be closed under addition and scalar multiplication. But $[1,0]+[0,1] = [1,1]$ which is definitely not in the set. Can someone clarify? Is the span a vector space, or not?

Comment: By definition, $[1,0] + [0,1] = [1,1]$ **is** in the span of the two vectors.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I don't understand, how is it in the span? And what is your take on if span{[1,0],[0,1]} is a vector space?

Comment: I mean, what's your definition of **span**? It should be by definition a subspace (the smallest subspace containing the given vectors - since you a finite number (actually 2) of vectors, it is also the set of all of their linear combinations), hence a vector space in its own right.

Comment: span = all linear combinations of [1,0] and [0,1]

Comment: oh. so we can x1[1,0] + x2[0,1] to get [1,1]?

Comment: @boolprop yes, with $x_1=1$ and $x_2=1$.

Answer (score 3):

$\mathrm{span}\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
0\\1
\end{bmatrix}\right\}$ is the set of linear combinations of the two vectors $\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0
\end{bmatrix}$
and $\begin{bmatrix}
0\\1
\end{bmatrix}$.

In other words, $\mathrm{span}\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
0\\1
\end{bmatrix}\right\}=\left\{a\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0
\end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix}
0\\1
\end{bmatrix}:a,b\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$.

Thus, $\begin{bmatrix}
1\\1
\end{bmatrix}$ is in the span.

In particular,  the two vectors $\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0
\end{bmatrix}$
and $\begin{bmatrix}
0\\1
\end{bmatrix}$ form the *standard basis* of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$. Thus, they span $\mathbb{R}^2$ and so do any two linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the (linear) span is a vector space. By definition it is the smallest vector space that contains all the elements in the set. In particular it will contain all linear combinations of those elements (and will in fact contain exactly all linear combinations that can be formed with those elements).

So in your example, if we consider $\{[1,0],[0,1]\} \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ we will get $$span\{[1,0],[0,1]\} = \mathbb{R}^{2}$$
because for every $[x,y] \in \mathbb{R}$ we can find a linear combination of $[1,0],[0,1]$ that represents $[x,y]$: 
$$x\cdot[1,0] + y\cdot[0,1] = [x,y].$$

With similar arguments we get 
get $$span\{[1,0]\} = \{[x,0] \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: x\in\mathbb{R}\}.$$

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span) is also a good starting point for more on linear spans.